# Edit Account - read and write to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, user-meta, account

I have user data that's being saved to and read from the database as they are all standard WordPress fields.

**example:** `$user->user_email`

[image: frontend and database]

**And here's the code I have inside the *form-edit-account.php*:**

```
<p class="form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="account_uid"><?php _e( 'UID-Nummer', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
            <input type="text" class="input-text" name="uidnumber" id="uidnumber" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->user_uidnumber ); ?>" />
        </p>
```

**Here's where I'm at right now:**

- Field does not write into database
- If value is entered via PHPMyAdmin value is read from database

**Essentially:** **Saving the value doesn't work/is missing.**

**Help is greatly appreciated!**

---

**One thing if I might add:**

I added a field in a different section of the website from a tutorial I found online.
[image: backend user]
I know it's kind of wrong to put it under `contact_methods`, but that's what I found:

```
function modify_contact_methods($profile_fields) {
    $profile_fields['uidnumber'] = 'UID-Nummer';    return $profile_fields;}
    add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'modify_contact_methods');

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );

function save_modified_contact_methods( $profile_fields ) {

    /* Copy and paste this line for additional fields. Make sure to change 'twitter' to the field ID. */
    update_usermeta( $profile_fields, 'uidnumber', $_POST['uidnumber'] );
}
```

And even though there seems to be something wrong with the `add_action`s, the code works and saves its data, but I have no idea where to. I can't find it in the `wp_usermeta` table

**I also do not know how to link those two fields together as I can't find the second one's database entry.**

To help be more specific about it, I'm uploading both my `functions.php` and the `form-edit-account.php`. Hopefully someone can figure out what's wrong.

- [form-edit-account.php](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4qnAW9zCJYLdEc3cGNUUG9yYXM/view?usp=sharing)
- [functions.php](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4qnAW9zCJYLblh4cTZQbk1XYWM/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User meta information, like that on the profile page, is stored in the `usermeta` table in the database.  You can add extra fields by hooking into the `show_user_profile` and `edit_user_profile` action hooks.  Then you can save the information by hooking into the `personal_options_update` and `edit_user_profile_update` action hooks with a function that updates the new field in the user meta table, `update_user_meta()`.

### First create the fields to be rendered on the profile page

```
//display extra profile fields
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_profile_fields' );

function extra_profile_fields( $user )
{
    ?>
        <h3>Extra Profile Fields</h3>

        <table class="form-table">
            <tr>
                <th><label for="UID-Nummer"><?php _e( 'UID-Nummer', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label></th>
                <td><input type="text" name="uid-nummer" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'uid-nummer', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <?php
}
```

Note the `name` attribute.  It's a good idea to use this same name when saving the field.  You can see that we are pulling that field into the value already using `get_the_author_meta( 'uid-nummer', $user->ID )`.

### Save the fields

```
//save extra profile fields
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_profile_fields' );

function save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id )
{
    update_user_meta( $user_id,'uid-nummer', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['uid-nummer'] ) );
}
```

### Using the fields

To display the field `ui-nummer` you can use either:

```
//return the author meta
get_the_author_meta( 'ui-nummer', $user->ID );
```

or

```
//echo the author meta
the_author_meta( 'ui-nummer', $user->ID );
```

Comment: Updated with a better answer.  Hope that helps.

Comment: It certainly helped, but I just can't seem to get it to actually save the value. No idea why though.
Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: In your functions.php file you have previous functions as well as the functions I gave above.  I would remove those and check.

Comment: Found myself a solution based on your information.
I finally found where the data was being saved to and reverse-engineered the input field to communicate with that database field.